# IIRF - How to send a 410 Gone response

Tags: regex, iirf, http-status-code-410

I am trying to use IIRF (Ionics Isapi Rewrite Filter V 2.1) to send a 410 Gone [G] response for URLs that contain the following string, but am very new to IIRF and regular expressions so a little lost as to how to properly form the rule.

I want to send the [G] for the following two cases

*-Resources.asp
*-Resources.html

Thanks,

Scott

Answer (score 0):

Well, on the off chance anyone else needs an answer to what turned out to be a stupidly easy question... here's what I used.

RedirectRule Resources /$1 [I,G]